# In Python, when does the class name become bound? I.e. when/where can we reference the class name w/o getting a `NameError`?

Tags: python, class, scope, identifier

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) says:

> the following will fail:

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = list(a + i for i in range(10))
```

I ran it and it and sure enough it fails: it throws `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. So I tried to fix by using `A.a` instead of `a` in the `list` argument:

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = list(A.a + i for i in range(10))
```

but that still didn't work. It throws `NameError: name **'A'** is not defined`.

When does the class name (in this case the `A` identifier) become bound such that we can reference it? I know that referencing `A` within a method of `A` is valid because when Python is parsing? the class definition, it doesn't execute the class methods. As an example, the following works:

```
class A:
    a = 42
    # b = list(A.a + i for i in range(10))
    
    def foo(self):
        print(A)

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print(A)

    @staticmethod
    def baz():
        print(A)

a = A()
a.foo()
a.bar()
a.baz()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is not bound until the class definition block completes. To quote the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax):

> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a class object is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the namespace created by the class definition; we’ll learn more about class objects in the next section. **The original local scope (the one in effect just before the class definition was entered) is reinstated, and the class object is bound here to the class name given in the class definition header** (ClassName in the example).

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the link. re: *"This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the namespace created by the class definition;"*, the *"namespace"* refers to the set of the class attributes (e.g. the names of the methods and other attributes) -- which may be the same as the set of keys in the class's `__dict__` attribute?

Comment: @joseville: Correct. The names in the class's namespace (the attributes and methods defined in the class block) are added to the class's `__dict__ at the end, when the class object is created.